# Converting string of 0 and 1 characters to hexadecimal string

Tags: c

I am converting all binary numbers stored in a file to hexadecimal. The file is parsed through command line argument, but to convert it to hexadecimal I want it to be converted to an integer, i.e. literal integer of the string received and `atoi()` doesn't seem to work.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    FILE *fp,*op;
    fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    op= fopen(argv[2],"w+");
    if( fp == NULL) 
    {
       perror("An error has occurred\n");
       exit(1);
    }

    char buff[1026];
    unsigned char hexstr[1024];
    unsigned long int hexnum,hexint;
    unsigned char four[4];
    int i, j,len;
    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp))
    {
        printf("\nString value = %s", buff);
        hexint=atoi(buff);
        printf("%ld",hexint);
    }

    fclose(fp); 
    fclose(op);
    return 0;
}
```

input file contains:

```
0000000000001010
1010000000000000
101010111100110111101111
000100100011010001010110
000100010001000100010001
011101110111011101110111
000000000000000000000000
```

output file should contain:

```
000a
a000
abcdef
123456
111111
777777
000000
```

Comment: What is the contents of the input file?  What is in the output file, and what *should* it contain?

Comment: input file contains multiple binary numbers, each in different lines and output file should contain hexadecimal
I should be good with the conversion but I am unable to convert string to its literal integer equivalent for the digit manipulations.

Comment: Don't describe the input/output, **show it**.

Comment: Input file contains 
0000000000001010
1010000000000000
101010111100110111101111
000100100011010001010110
000100010001000100010001
011101110111011101110111
000000000000000000000000
o/p file should contain:
000a
a000
abcdef
123456
111111
777777
000000

Comment: @rohithp Could you put the contents of the output file into your question right under the code?

Comment: code changes made and expected output added. 
Thank you!

Comment: Once answers arrive do not fundamentally change code. If desired you can post your own answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `atoi` function expects the input text to be in decimal format, but you're feeding it binary.  Also, you're using the `%d` format specifier to print, which output decimal format.

You need to use the `strtoul` function for the conversion instead and specify base 2 for the input.  Then for the output, use the `%x` format specifier to print in hex.

```
while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp))
{      printf("\nString value = %s", buff);
       hexint=strtoul(buff, NULL, 2);
       printf("%lx",hexint);
}
```

If you want the number of digits printed to vary based on the length of the input text, you can specify a field width of `*` and pass the number of digits as an extra parameter, and also add the `0` flag to pad on the left with zeros.

Since you have the binary string, and there are 4 binary digits to 1 hex digits, divide the length of the binary string by 4 and round up to get the number of digits:

```
       hexint=strtoul(buff, NULL, 2);
       int bindigits = strlen(buff);
       int hexdigits = (bindigits % 4 == 0) ? bindigits / 4 : bindigits / 4 + 1;
       printf("%0*lx", hexdigits, hexint);
```

Comment: for the input "0000000000001010" it gives me the output "a", but expected output is "000a"

Comment: @rohithp If you want at least 4 digits to be printed, set the field width to 4 and use the 0 flag to specify left padding with zeros, i.e. `%04lx`

Comment: That works for printing, but when i want to write it back to an output file, it wouldn't, neither with fprintf nor with fputs and its not specific for 4 digits, it is generic(for how many ever digits the user enters in the input file).

Comment: the format specifier is the same for the printf family, so it should work for fprintf. `fputs` doesn't receive a format string so you can't use it in this case

Comment: it gives me the following error after making those changes.
 In function ‘main’:
3.c:22:20: error: expected expression before ‘%’ token
         fprintf(op,%04lx);
                    ^
3.c:22:21: error: invalid suffix "lx" on integer constant
         fprintf(op,%04lx);
                     ^~~~

Comment: @rohithp You forgot the quotes around the format string.

Comment: Suggest adding `'\n'`, so `printf("%lx\n",hexint);` to separate values.

Comment: @dbush Wouldn't have it been simpler for you to edit your answer and just change the prinftf??

Comment: @dbush Thank you, but i want the output to be generic, in case the input has 00000000000000001010, output would be 0000a and "%04lx" wouldn't help. I hope you understand.

Comment: @rohithp See my edit.  You can specify the field width as a separate parameter.

Answer (score 1):

For this conversion assignment, Using `fgets()` might pose a problem if the line length can be arbitrary.

You can convert the contents on the fly, one byte at a time and pass any non binary digits to the output unchanged:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp, *op;
    int c, hasnum;
    unsigned long long num;

    if (argc < 3
    ||  ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL
    ||  ((op = fopen(argv[2], "w")) == NULL) {
       perror("Error opening files\n");
       return 1;
    }
    hasnum = 0;
    num = 0;

    for (;;) {
        c = getc(fp);
        if (c == '0' || c == '1') {
            num = num * 2 + (c - '0');
            hasnum++;
        } else {
            if (hasnum) {
                // output one hex digit for 4 input binary digits
                fprintf(fo, "%0*x", (hasnum + 3) / 4, num);
                hasnum = 0;
                num = 0;
            }
            if (c == EOF)
                break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp); 
    fclose(op);
    return 0;
}
```